# Cannot seem to crawl a deep directory with my Python script, any idea?

Tags: python, recursion, web-crawler, directory

The script is basically creating a list with all the files in all directories. Any idea why is seems to crash when it has to scan a directory that is larger than a few files?

```
import os

correctlyNamedDirectories = []

def crawlDirectories(directory):
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            correctlyNamedDirectories.append(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))
        for filename in filenames:
            correctlyNamedDirectories.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

crawlDirectories('.')

print correctlyNamedDirectories
```

Also, is there a cleaner way of writing this?

Comment: *Crash*? Any particular error, or do you mean it segfaults?

Comment: If you want to know if there's a better way of writing some code, you might want to consider [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter method with a list comprehension:

```
correctlyNamedDirectories = [os.path.join(path, subname) for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory) for subname in dirnames + filenames]
```

Comment: Corrected as ``os.path.join()`` didn't have a closing bracket and doesn't take a list.